# Camel HTTP Endpoint: How to set URL-String to POST Parameter

Tags: java, http, http-post, apache-camel

**Prerequisites**

- Apache Tomcat 7
- Spring 3.2.11.RELEASE
- Apache Camel 2.14.1
- Camel HTTP Endpoint (`<artifactId>camel-http</artifactId>`)

**Problem**

At the moment I use following code to set POST-Parameters to the message body.
The camel HTTP-Component reads the parameters and sends it.

```
.setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant(HttpMethods.POST.name()))
.setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset: UTF-8"))
.setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_ENCODING, constant("UTF-8"))
.setBody("parameter1=a&parameter2=b")
```

The problem ist that some parameters are URLs itself.
So something like this should be send as POST-Request:

```
postparameter1=a&postparameter2=http://www.`...`.com?urlparam1=value1&urlparam2=value2&postparameter3=b
```

My question is how to send "http://www.`...`.com?urlparam1=value1&urlparam2=value2" as value of postparameter2.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Max

Comment: Have you tried using [`java.net.URLEncode.encode`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As isim mentioned above, following works for me.
The idea is to parse a given url fist and to encode it again afterwards.
This avoids double encoding.

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.*;

public static String getEncodedURL(String urlString) {
    final String encodedURL;
    try {
        String decodedURL = URLDecoder.decode(urlString, "UTF-8");
        URL url = new URL(decodedURL);
        URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
        final URL urlFromDecoding = uri.toURL();
        encodedURL = URLEncoder.encode(urlFromDecoding.toString(), "UTF-8");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        ...
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        ...
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        ...
    }
    return encodedURL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I mentioned here how to send string message through camel HTTP post, I hope this will help to you.Another one is we need to add basic rest authentication.Username and password is your app rest authentication credentials.

```
from("seda:httpSender")  
    .log("Inside Http sender")
    .process(new Processor(){
        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
            // Camel will populate all request.parameter and request.headers, 
            // no need for placeholders in the "from" endpoint
            String content = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);      

            System.out.println("Outbound message string : "+content);

            // This URI will override http://dummyhost
            exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_URI, "http://localhost:9090/httpTest");

            // Add input path. This will override the original input path.
            // If you need to keep the original input path, then add the id to the 
            // URI above instead
         //   exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_PATH, id);

            // Add query parameter such as "?name=xxx"
            exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY, "outboundMessage="+content);  
            exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, "POST");
        }
    })
    .doTry()
    .log("Message added as a parameter")
    .to("http4://localhost:9090/httpTest?authMethod=Basic&authPassword=admin&authUsername=admin")
    .log("HTTP message transfer success")
    .doCatch(Exception.class)
    .log("HTTP message transfer failed")
    .end();
```